# How to change an specific part of an image colour?

Tags: image-processing, color

I'm not so sure whether this questions fits here, but I need help in this case, cause I'm searching for days to apply this.

I have a website of rugs and carpets, in this website I would like customers to be able to change the rug colour by clicking on some part of a rug and change the colour using colour-picker.

For example if we click on red part of the rug and selected yellow from colour-picker, all the reds change into yellow in that rug.

Personally I'm a Unity C# developer, but I guess there should be other development environment or libraries which can make this easier to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your helps

Comment: You'd probably be best off using an off-the-shelf image processing library.  Most systems that allow users to play with colours start with a monochrome version of the image, and (behind the scenes) a map to indicate to the application which areas to colour in when the user clicks.

Comment: Basically I agree with what he said
another option would be to download an imaging tool.

Comment: Please consider upvoting/following the StackExchange Color Theory site: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110687/color-theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing a single color

1. Generate a opacity mask (alpha channel) by computing the color distance between each pixel to the color-to-be-replaced.

   - A zero distance (i.e. matching exactly the color to be replaced) corresponds to zero opacity (i.e. fully transparent, such that its original pixel color will be ignored)
   - Opacity increases as the color distance increases. You will need to define your own mapping function to control the sensitivity.
2. Perform an alpha blend between the original image and a solid color image filled with the new color, using the opacity mask that was computed in the first step.

Replacing an entire spectrum, e.g. hue rotation

- Some types of color changes may be performed by converting into another color space and performing simple modular arithmetic.
- Some types of color changes can be performed by linear algebra, see [`ColorMatrix` (msdn.microsoft.com)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix(v=vs.110).aspx)